# Installation of java-deobfuscator on windows (version with GUI) - can't found a JVM with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, deobfuscation

I am trying to install: https://github.com/java-deobfuscator/deobfuscator-gui
The problem is that on my computer (Windows 10) it doesn't start, but I do the right things: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhIeW.png (I just removed the input for other tests)

Config folder :

```
input: input.jar
output: output.jar
detect: false
transformers:
  - special.SuperblaubeereTransformer
```

If someone has an idea I'm a taker here is the error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL4TH.png

Comment: Even though the error is a GUI alert,  it is best to also copy the error text and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
You need a JVM with JavaFX
```

Some JRE providers create these, e.g:

- Bellsoft Liberica
- Amazon Corretto
- Azul Zulu

Or, you can create your own JRE using `jlink`.

For more information on creating a JRE with JavaFX, see the openjfx.io getting started documentation on Runtime Images.